# Error de compilación en módulo oculto - VBA

Tags: vba

He creado una macro donde rellenas una plantilla y esta la puedes copiar y enviar lo seleccionado por correo.

Me funciona perfectamente en Excel 2013, pero si lo quiero utilizar en otro ordenador que no tenga la misma versión esta me da un error:

> "Error de compilación modulo oculto: correos, este error suele ocurrir
>   cuando el código es incompatible con la versión"

También cuando salgo del Excel, este si lo vuelvo abrir se queda bloqueado.
En Excel desarrollador->herramientas->referencias; tengo marcado, Adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo realizar las macros en Excel 2010 para que sean compatibles en versiones distintas?

---

Adjunto el código para los envios de correo, me funciona bien. Lo que pasa que cuando cierro el Excel, este me deja como una hoja en blanco:

```
Sub correo()


Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)


Dim envio As String
Dim copia As String
Dim Asunto As String

'Subject
Asunto = Envío correo Plantilla

'ADJUNTO EN CUERPO DEL CORREO EL RANGO SELECIONADO.

 Worksheets("datosplantilla").Range("A1:P12").Select
 Selection.Copy


 With olMail

.To = envio
.Subject = Asunto
.CC = copia
.Body = " PLANTILLA OBA"
' PARA PODER ADJUNTO LO SELECCIONADO, HAY QUE AÑADIR Display, SendKeys Y        DoEvents, SI NO QUIERES LOS QUITAS.
.Display
    SendKeys "^({v})", True
    DoEvents

 .Send


 End With


 End Sub
```

Comment: El problema es la macro o outlook?? yo me tiraria mas a que el problema es que tu referencia a outlook no existe en la maquina destino

Comment: Hola, gbianchi, me funciona bien, solo es cuando lo ejecuto en otro ordenador, he realizado una prueba, tenia este código al cerrar lo he comentado y parece que ya esta solucionado el problema que daba                                                                                                        Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
'Sheets("plantillaoba").Select
'Call BORRADO_PLANTILLAOBA
'ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True

End Sub

Comment: Entonces si ya encontraste la solucion al problema, por favor agrega una respuesta..

Comment: Hola, no esta solucionado, he quitado el problema para abrir el archivo, pero enviarlo por correo me sigue dando el error, aun con el envio de los correos, aun activando la referencia del Outlook, versión14, este me da un error en  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application y no me deja seguir.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder solucionar el problema que tenia, he tenido que quitar la clave que tenia para que no pudieran modificar el código, quitando la clave pueden entrar a

`Herramientas->referencias-> y activar el Outlook`

Según la versión de **Excel** que tiene cada usuario y funciona a la perfección, el código lo he modificado comentado `.Send` y de esta manera puedo ver el correo antes de enviar y perfecto.